# PHP If Time is Weekend EST Then X, Else Y

Tags: php, http-headers

Can anyone help me with the php code needed to do a header redirect using 2 URLs, where the user goes to URL 1 if the time is Mon-Friday Eastern Standard Time, else goes to URL 2 if time is Saturday-Sunday EST?

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$weeekday = "http://google.com";
$weekend = "http://yahoo.com";

function isWeekend($date) {
    if (date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 6) {
    $link = $weekend;
    }
    else {
    $link = $weeekday;
    };
};

header("location: ". $link);

?>
```

The above gets a "The page isn’t redirecting properly" error.

Comment: We can probably _help_, yes. But you need to give us a starting point. Please show what you have tried and describe how the result differed from what you wanted.

Comment: http://php.net/date, the `N` parameter, and an if/else should do it.

Comment: Maybe use Carbon: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ - if($dt->isWeekend()){ echo 'Weekend'; } else{ echo 'Not weekend'; }

Comment: Also show how you're calling that function (including sample input)

Comment: You need to call the function, put `isWeekend($date);` at the end.

Comment: Yeah I'm lost. Trying to understand, but not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a function that you never call. Either remove the function "header" or call the function and return the link.

Remove function:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$weeekday = "http://google.com";
$weekend = "http://yahoo.com";


    if (date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 6) {
    $link = $weekend;
    }
    else {
    $link = $weeekday;
    };

header('location: '. $link);
```

Return method:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

function isWeekend($date) {
    $weeekday = "http://google.com";
    $weekend = "http://yahoo.com";

    if (date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 6) {
    $link = $weekend;
    }
    else {
    $link = $weeekday;
    };
    return $link;
};
$link = isWeekend($date);
header('location: '. $link);
```

Comment: Thanks! Just edited my post with your first response, which I just posted the same time you posted here. Trial and error I got it. Appreciate the explanation!

Comment: I advice you to undo your edit of the question. Questions are questions, not a mix of question and answer. It will be confusing and some will probably downvote it.  Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing. I didn't edit with your answer, I was editing with the same conclusion as you and asking if that was the best way to do it. Just coincidence. But I will go ahead and remove the edit so it's not confusing to other users.

Comment: I know you didn't use my code. That is not what I meant, I'm sorry if you read it that way.